# Dit-on « Il a des fantasmes envers son enseignant » ou « Il a des fantasmes pour son enseignant »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

J’ai consulté plusieurs dictionnaires et aucun en fait mention. Par ailleurs, l’Académie de la langue française recommande peu l’emploi de « fantasmer sur », d’où mon effort pour trouver une tournure qui réponde au bon usage. J’hésite entre « avoir des fantasmes envers son enseignant », « avoir des fantasmes sur son enseignant » et « avoir des fantasmes pour son enseignant. » Quelle règle dicte l’usage de l’une ou l’autre des prépositions? Merci.

*On dit bien « Il éprouve des désirs pour sa conjointe ». J’aurais donc tendance à m’inspirer de cette formulation pour écrire la phrase en question.

Comment: Plus que l'académie française,  je me demande si l'éducation nationale trouve que fantasmer sur un enseignant est recommandable...

Comment: Plus sérieusement : on dirait plutôt "éprouver *du* désir pour quelqu'un ".

Comment: Merci Greg pour tes renseignements.

Comment: Est-ce qu'on dit vraiment *il éprouve des désirs pour sa conjointe* ? Je ne l'ai jamais entendu et google ne trouve aucune occurence, même en retirant *conjointe*. Ce qui passe mieux serait: *il éprouve **du désir** pour sa conjointe*.

Answer (score 4):

La forme correcte est "avoir des fantasmes SUR quelqu'un":

> Il a des fantasmes sur son enseignant.

... ou encore "fantasmer SUR quelqu'un":

> Il fantasme sur son enseignant.

Answer (score 0):

Ni « envers » ni « pour » ne conviennent mais comme cela a été dit dans une autre réponse, « sur » est une  préposition appropriée ; on peut trouver maints exemples sur cette [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22phantasmes%20sur%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

L'usage d'une proposition est une bonne chose, pratique et sûre lorsqu'un usage est bien établi mais une locution ou une courte subordonnée à le mérite, lorsqu'elle est bien tournée, d'ajouter de la substance ; voilà un cas où ce principe trouve une application fructueuse.

- Il  a des phantasmes  **dans lesquels domine (la personne de)** son enseignant
- **hantés par** son enseignant
- **peuplés essentiellement par** son enseignant
- **dont le caratère central est** son enseignant

Fournir d'autres possibilités propres à exprimer des notions plus intéressantes encore  n'est qu'une question d'imagination.